# Getting ranges that are not in database

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I want to get all times that an event is not taking place for each room. The start of the day is `9:00:00` and end is `22:00:00`.

What my database looks like is this:

```
Event       EventStart  EventEnd    Days                Rooms   DayStarts
CISC 3660   09:00:00    12:30:00    Monday              7-3     9/19/2014   
MATH 2501   15:00:00    17:00:00    Monday:Wednesday    7-2     10/13/2014  
CISC 1110   14:00:00    16:00:00    Monday              7-3     9/19/2014
```

I want to get the times that aren't in the database.

ex. For SelectedDate (9/19/2014) the table should return:

```
Room  FreeTimeStart  FreeTimeEnd
7-3   12:30:00       14:00:00
7-3   16:00:00       22:00:00
```

ex2. SelectedDate (10/13/2014):

```
Room  FreeTimeStart  FreeTimeEnd
7-2    9:00:00       15:00:00
7-2   17:00:00       22:00:00
```

What I have tried is something like this:

```
select * from Events where ________ NOT BETWEEN eventstart AND eventend;
```

But I do not know what to put in the place of the space.

Comment: Is there any limit of time when the event start and end? Like minimum time of event is 1 hour etc.

Comment: The minimum is 30 mins and there is no max

Comment: I will not provide you the code, because i am not at the desktop but i will provide you the pseudocode that i think will be usefull
`get first date from Events and check if it is equal 9:00:00, if not add record to free time as from 9:00:00 to this date, else select the enddate of this record and threat it like startdate of free time and repeat it until there is no next date, or date is not equal 22:00:00`
You can use cursor (which is the slow option) otherwise you can use temporary table.

Comment: @User765876, can the length of events be anything other than half an hour?

Comment: yes, they can be any lengths.

Comment: So you could theoretically have a meeting from `12:30:00` to `13:12:52`? In that case, do you want the 'free time' to start at `13:12:53`, `13:15:00`', or `13:30:00`?

Comment: the free time should start at 13:12:53

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: it is sql-server 2014

Answer (score 1):

This was a pretty complex request.  SQL works best with sets, and not looking at line by line.  Here is what I came up with.  To make it easier to figure out, I wrote it as a series of CTE's so I could work through the problem a step at a time.  I am not saying that this is the best possible way to do it, but it doesn't require the use of any cursors.  You need the Events table and a table of the room names (otherwise, you don't see a room that doesn't have any bookings).

Here is the query and I will explain the methodology.

```
DECLARE @Events TABLE (Event varchar(20), EventStart Time, EventEnd Time, Days varchar(50), Rooms varchar(10), DayStarts date)

INSERT INTO @Events
SELECT 'CISC 3660',   '09:00:00',    '12:30:00',    'Monday',              '7-3',     '9/19/2014' UNION
SELECT 'MATH 2501',   '15:00:00',    '17:00:00',    'Monday:Wednesday',    '7-2',     '10/13/2014' UNION
SELECT 'CISC 1110',   '14:00:00',    '16:00:00',    'Monday',              '7-3',     '9/19/2014' 

DECLARE @Rooms TABLE (RoomName varchar(10))
INSERT INTO @Rooms
SELECT '7-2' UNION 
SELECT '7-3'

DECLARE @SelectedDate date = '9/19/2014'
DECLARE @MinTimeInterval int = 30 --smallest time unit room can be reserved for
;WITH
  D1(N) AS (
            SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL
            SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL
            SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1
           ),
  D2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM D1 a, D1 b),
  D4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM D2 a, D2 b),
  Numbers AS (SELECT TOP 3600 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) -1 AS Number FROM D4),
  AllTimes AS 
    (SELECT CAST(DATEADD(n,Numbers.Number*@MinTimeInterval,'09:00:00') as time) AS m FROM Numbers
    WHERE DATEADD(n,Numbers.Number*@MinTimeInterval,'09:00:00') <= '22:00:00'),
  OccupiedTimes AS (
    SELECT e.Rooms, ValidTimes.m
    FROM @Events E
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT m FROM AllTimes WHERE m BETWEEN CASE WHEN e.EventStart = '09:00:00' THEN e.EventStart ELSE DATEADD(n,1,e.EventStart) END and CASE WHEN e.EventEnd = '22:00:00' THEN e.EventEnd ELSE DATEADD(n,-1,e.EventEnd) END) ValidTimes
    WHERE e.DayStarts = @SelectedDate
    ),
    AllRoomsAllTimes AS (
        SELECT * FROM @Rooms R CROSS JOIN AllTimes
    ), AllOpenTimes AS (
    SELECT a.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY (a.RoomName) ORDER BY a.m) AS pos
    FROM AllRoomsAllTimes A
    LEFT OUTER JOIN OccupiedTimes o ON a.RoomName = o.Rooms AND a.m = o.m
    WHERE o.m IS NULL
    ), Finalize AS (
    SELECT a1.RoomName,
        CASE WHEN a3.m IS NULL OR  DATEDIFF(n,a3.m, a1.m) > @MinTimeInterval THEN a1.m else NULL END AS FreeTimeStart,
        CASE WHEN a2.m IS NULL OR DATEDIFF(n,a1.m,a2.m) > @MinTimeInterval THEN A1.m ELSE NULL END AS FreeTimeEnd,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER( ORDER BY a1.RoomName )  AS Pos
    FROM AllOpenTimes A1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN AllOpenTimes A2 ON a1.RoomName = a2.RoomName and a1.pos = a2.pos-1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN AllOpenTimes A3 ON a1.RoomName = a3.RoomName and a1.pos = a3.pos+1
    WHERE A2.m IS NULL OR DATEDIFF(n,a1.m,a2.m) > @MinTimeInterval
    OR
    A3.m IS NULL OR DATEDIFF(n,a3.m, a1.m) > @MinTimeInterval
    )
    SELECT F1.RoomName, f1.FreeTimeStart, f2.FreeTimeEnd FROM Finalize F1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Finalize F2 ON F1.Pos = F2.pos-1 AND f1.RoomName = f2.RoomName
    WHERE f1.pos % 2 = 1
```

In the first several lines, I create temp variables to simulate your tables Events and Rooms.
The variable @MinTimeInterval determines what time interval the room schedules can be on (every 30 min, 15 min, etc - this number needs to divide evenly into 60).

Since SQL cannot query data that is missing, we need to create a table that holds all of the times that we want to check for.  The first several lines in the WITH create a table called AllTimes which are all the possible time intervals in your day.

Next, we get a list of all of the times that are occupied (OccupiedTimes), and then LEFT OUTER JOIN this table to the AllTimes table which gives us all the available times.  Since we only want the start and end of each free time, create the Finalize table which self joins each record to the previous and next record in the table.  If the times in these rows are greater than @MinTimeInterval, then we know it is either a start or end of a free time.

Finally we self join this last table to put the start and end times in the same row and only look at every other row.

This will need to be adjusted if a single row in Events spans multiple days or multiple rooms.

Comment: it doesnt give the correct answer:                                 for 7-2     `09:00:00.0000000 22:00:00.0000000` for 
7-3 `12:30:00.0000000 14:00:00.0000000` for 
7-3 `16:00:00.0000000 22:00:00.0000000`

Comment: Replace the where clause in OccupiedTimes (WHERE e.DayStarts = @SelectedDate) with WHERE CHARINDEX(DATENAME(dw,@Selecteddate),e.Days,0) > 0 AND e.DayStarts >= @SelectedDate

Comment: Also, there is no end date, so with the '10/13/2014' example, it is a monday, so both rooms would show.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that will return the "complete picture" including rooms that aren't booked at all for the day in question:

```
Declare @Date char(8) = '20141013'
;
WITH cte as
(
    SELECT *
    FROM -- use your table name instead of the VALUES construct
    (VALUES
    ('09:00:00','12:30:00' ,'7-3', '20140919'),
    ('15:00:00','17:00:00' ,'7-2', '20141013'),
    ('14:00:00','16:00:00' ,'7-3', '20140919')) x(EventStart , EventEnd,Rooms, DayStarts)
), cte_Days_Rooms AS
-- get a cartesian product for the day specified and all rooms as well as the start and end time to compare against
(
    SELECT y.EventStart,y.EventEnd, x.rooms,a.DayStarts FROM 
    (SELECT @Date DayStarts) a
    CROSS JOIN
    (SELECT DISTINCT Rooms FROM cte)x
    CROSS JOIN
    (SELECT '09:00:00' EventStart,'09:00:00' EventEnd UNION ALL
     SELECT '22:00:00' EventStart,'22:00:00' EventEnd) y        
), cte_1 AS
-- Merge the original data an the "base data"
(
    SELECT * FROM cte WHERE DayStarts=@Date
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM cte_Days_Rooms
), cte_2 as
-- use the ROW_NUMBER() approach to sort the data
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY DayStarts, Rooms ORDER BY EventStart) as pos
    FROM cte_1
)
-- final query: self join with an offest of one row, eliminating duplicate rows if a room is booked starting 9:00 or ending 22:00
SELECT c2a.DayStarts, c2a.Rooms , c2a.EventEnd, c2b.EventStart 
FROM cte_2 c2a
INNER JOIN cte_2 c2b on c2a.DayStarts = c2b.DayStarts AND c2a.Rooms =c2b.Rooms AND c2a.pos = c2b.pos -1
WHERE c2a.EventEnd <> c2b.EventStart
ORDER BY c2a.DayStarts, c2a.Rooms
```

Comment: I took out line 7-10 and added my table name ( `[events]` ) but it is giving me an error. `Invalid object name 'Events'.`

Comment: Now the error i get is `All queries combined using a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator must have an equal number of expressions in their target lists. `